# Peculiar subspace for a measure on infinite-dimensional separable Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, banach-spaces

> Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional separable Banach space, and $P$ be a Borel probability measure on $E$. There exists $F$ verifying the following conditions:
>
> - $F$ is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $E$,
> - $F$ is a vector subspace of $E$,
> - $F\subsetneqq E$,
> - $P(F)=1$.

I'm looking for a proof of this fact, which is Exercise 7 p.82 in this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9027724962): [image]

As Eric Wofsey points out, $F$ is not necessarily unique, so I've removed this part of the question.

Here's the theorem mentioned in the hint:[image]

Since $E$ is Polish, $P$ is a Radon measure, hence there exists a separable Borel set $A$ with $P(A)=1$. However this doesn't help much.

Since $E$ is separable, there is an increasing sequence of finite-dimensional subspaces $G_n$ such that $\bigcup_n G_n$ is dense in $E$, but that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: This cannot be true as written.  For instance, if $P$ is concentrated on a single point, then $F$ could be any closed proper subspace that contains that point, so $F$ is not unique.

Comment: @EricWofsey Of course, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the main point of Theorem 3.1, which is that the set $C_\epsilon$ is totally bounded and hence compact if $X$ is complete.  So, taking union of such sets as $\epsilon\to 0$, there is a $\sigma$-compact set $S$ such that $P(S)=1$.  Now let $F$ be the span of $S$.  Since $S$ is $\sigma$-compact, so is $F$ (for each compact $K\subset S$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the set of linear combinations of $n$ elements of $K$ with coefficients of absolute value $\leq n$ is compact, and $F$ is the union of these sets).  In particular, then, $F$ is Borel, and also $F$ is not all of $E$ since $E$ is not $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Thank you. There's a typo, you mean $\epsilon\to 0$.